# Linux regulator user space consume driver : missing state under sysfs

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device, device-tree

I'm trying to use the [reg-userspace-consumer](https://www.studiofuga.com/2019/07/18/adding-a-user-space-power-switch-to-your-embedded-linux) driver to turn on/off a USB bus supply. Looks like the the driver was back-ported to [4.4.143](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.143/source/drivers/regulator/userspace-consumer.c). All I had to do is to compile the kernel with the driver:

```
CONFIG_REGULATOR_USERSPACE_CONSUMER=y
```

and link it with the targeted regulator through the device tree :

```
    vcc_otg_vbus: otg-vbus-regulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        enable-active-high;
        gpio = <&gpio0 RK_PC5 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&otg_vbus_drv>;
        regulator-name = "vcc_otg_vbus";
    };

    vcc_otg_vbus_switch {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "reg-userspace-consumer";
        regulator-name = "vcc-otg-vbus-consumer";
        #regulator-boot-on;
        regulator-supplies = "vbus";
        vbus-supply = <&vcc_otg_vbus>;
        comment = "USB OTG power switch";
    };
```

The sysfs hook does show up but it's missing the **state** file :

```
root# ls /sys/devices/platform/vcc_otg_vbus_switch/
driver_override  modalias         of_node          power            subsystem        uevent
```

As far as I can see, the driver doesn't provide more control over the regulator from user space than *regulator-fixed*. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you miss the point *when* it's appropriate to use such regulator type. I have no wonder why it's not working.

Comment: @Oandriy please enlight me. When is it appropriate to use such regulator type?

Comment: I guess none for USB OTG case. If you want to have the possibility to handle VBUS in userspace, you need to hack the corresponding UDC driver.

Comment: OTG is just a label. Not sure why the manufacturer used it. Based on the schematics, it simply drives vbus from a type-A host only connector.

Answer (score 0):

The driver was upstream but the patch as described [here](https://www.studiofuga.com/2019/07/18/adding-a-user-space-power-switch-to-your-embedded-linux/) wasn't applied.